# Android - What is the right way to save/restore a ListView adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to save/restore, in changing orientation, a `List<Contact>` instance for a `ListView`; `Contact` is the item to show in a custom array adapter.

I'm saving the List underlying the adapter in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savingInstanceState)` activity method:

```
savingInstanceState.putSerializable(""+R.id.contactList, (Serializable)adapter.contacts());
```

Then in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` I restore and set the adapter:

```
    List<Contact> contacts =  
        (List<Contact>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(""+R.id.contactList);
    ContactListAdapter adapter = 
        new ContactListAdapter((Context)this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
    contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is it the right way to do it?

Do you have a better/smarter solution?

Thank you

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? If it's already on the device, just query it again.

Comment: @herbalessence I disagree. As far I can see it seems regarding to how/when/whether update Adapter data from which type of thread. Thank you.

Comment: @alexanderblom Data come from Internet, but when I change orientation they _are_ already on the device; just inside the adapter ;)